# Android Draw SVG Path on canvas with animation

Tags: android, svg, path, draw

I have a SVG path and Paint to draw path on canvas and I used
`canvas.drawPath(path.getSvgPath(), path.getSvgFillPaint());` it is work properly and now I want to add animation  when fill path with given Paint. loke Happy Color App  [Happy Color](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.pixel.art.coloring.color.number) 
if you have a any idea please reply this.
thank you

Answer (score 1):

Use a timer or thread or Animate class to change what path.getSvgFillPaint's fillOpacity gradually down to 0.
Every time when the fillOpacity changes, call View's postInvalidate to redraw the canvas, you will see it fade out gradually.